# preg_replace href value only if there string x is not found in it

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with the following situation

I want to replace the href value with preg_replace and dont know how

I got 3 types of links

```
1:<a href="http://www.something.com"></a>
2:<a href="smartlink:webview-something"></a>
3:<a href="link/to/something"></a>
```

I want to add the domain on link 3 (http://www.something.com/link/to/something)
but 1 and 2 should stay untouched.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $new_link = preg_replace("/href=\\"(?!(http|smartlink))(.*)\\">/", "http://www.something.com/$2", $str);
```

Click on preg_replace
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fJ9

Comment: @MartinAlt Parse error?? That is odd. Have you replaced the `$str` with your string variable?